# Efficiently appying a custom function on data.frame column which is itself a list of data.frames

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have a JSON file with 1M+ records. I created a custom function to filter on C = 1 and calculate a simple difference.

The JSON file has the following structure. After reading into R data.frame the column "Group" is a list of data.frames.

"JSON_data.txt":

```
{"ID":1,"Group":[{"A":0,"B":"10.62","C":1},{"A":0,"B":"10.61","C":2},{"A":1,"B":"11.37","C":1},{"A":1,"B":"11.4","C":2}]}
{"ID":2,"Group":[{"A":0,"B":"10.65","C":1},{"A":0,"B":"10.63","C":2},{"A":1,"B":"11.31","C":1},{"A":1,"B":"11.50","C":2}]}
```

[image]

After reading in with jasonlite I generate 2000 records for illustration purpose)

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

## Read JSON file / stream in
json_data <- stream_in(file("JSON_data.txt"), verbose = TRUE)

# simulate 2000 records by repeating
multiplied <- json_data[rep(seq_len(nrow(json_data)), each=1000),]

# custom function
get_difference <- function(x){

  # create a temporary data.frame
  temp <- as.data.frame(x) %>% 
    filter(C == 1) %>% # filter on C = 1
    mutate(B = as.numeric(B)) %>% #put B values to numeric
    select(A, B, C)

  if (nrow(temp) < 2){  # if less than two records, put NA
    difference <- NA
  } else {

    difference <- (filter(temp, A == 1)[2] - filter(temp, A == 0)[2])

  }
  return(difference)

}


multiplied$difference <- sapply(multiplied[, 2], function(x) get_difference(x))
```

**Using sapply on 2000 records takes appr. a minute!**
**QUESTION: How to speed up this calculation on a big data.frame?**

Comment: Is there a bracket and a newline missing in the input data?

Comment: I get an error reading your JSON_data.txt `Error: parse error: after array element, I expect ',' or ']'`

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was a missing bracket - just corrected and added a screenshot from Notepad++

Comment: Are you expecting always exactly one ´ A==0;C==1 ´ and one ´ A==1;C==1 ´? If less you return NA, but what if there are more?

Comment: On C==1 it will be at maximum two records (could be one either side or zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your expected output is, but data.table may be a good starting point to speed things up..

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

## Read JSON file / stream in
json_data <- stream_in(file("JSON_data.txt"), verbose = TRUE)

# simulate 2000 records by repeating
multiplied <- json_data[rep(seq_len(nrow(json_data)), each=1000),]

dt <- data.table::rbindlist(multiplied$Group)[C == 1,]
dt[, B := as.numeric(B)]
dt[ , difference := ifelse( A == 0, B - shift( B, n = 1L, fill = NA, type = "lead"), NA)]
multiplied$difference = dt[A == 0, difference]
```

Comment: Yeaaaaaahhhhh, it took 2 seconds on 2 Mio

Comment: @user1766682 BEHOLD.. the power of data.table ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This one works instantly for me:

```
get_difference <- function(x){
    idx0 = which(x$C==1 & x$A==0)
    idx1 = which(x$C==1 & x$A==1)
    if(length(idx1)==length(idx0))
        diff(as.numeric(x$B[c(idx1, idx0)]), lag=length(idx1))
    else
        NA
}
```

Comment: Yes, already a great significant improvement! Just tryed on 2 Mio records - It takes 3 Minutes on my machine